# I have trouble understanding simple equality passage

Tags: unit-of-measure

I don't know why I always have trouble with these things, there is something that must do 'click' in my head.

Knowing that `1000000 cm³ = 1 m³`, how do you get that

```
    cm³
-----------
 0,000001 m³`?
```

It is pretty obvious visually that `1 cm³ = 0,000001 m³`, but how to do it matematically? It is for unit conversion.

`1000000 cm³ = 1 m³`

```
   1 cm³ = 1 m³
          ------
           1000000
```

then

```
1 =    1 m³
      ------      Now i'm lost!
       1000000
    ---------- 
        cm³
```

Comment: though I don't see where you might be confused, your last statement should be
$ 1 = \left(\frac{1m^3}{1000000}\right)/(1cm^3)$
Also, 1m=100cm, so change accordingly

Comment: @tpb261 I am confused in how to get to cm³ above 0,000001 m³

Comment: I think you are trying to solve some other problem, if that is the case, you can replace all $cm^3$ with $0.000001 m^3$ or $m^3$ with $1000000 cm^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is `1000 cm³ = 1 m³` is FALSE.

```
1 m = 100 cm
```

so

```
1 m³ = (100 cm)³ = 1000000 cm³
```

Comment: Thanks, thats a good spot, but how do you get to cm³ / 0,000001 m³ ? I need it that way so I can cancel cm³ with cm³ when converting units

Comment: In arithmetics you just handle a unit as a separate term in multiplication. So if we say `1m=100cm` we can divide both sides of the equation by `1m` to get `1=(100cm)/(1m)`. You can raise both sides to a power: `(1)³=((100cm)/(1m))³` which results in `1=(100cm)³/(1m)³ = (100³ cm³)/(m³) = 1000000 cm³/m³`. You can, of course, also multiply enumerator and denominator by the same value, say `1/1000000`, so finally `1 = (1 cm³)/(0,000001 m³)`.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was needing, a dumb-proof exaplanation